# Create better types from GraphQL response

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql

I am using GraphQL and have a big problem with the types. I like to make a request and save the result to a React state. There I would like to have a nice type. But I don't want to say `const [animals, setAnimals] = useState<AnimalsListQueryResponse>()`, because I should call my animals later as `animals.edges[number].node.name`. I would prefer to have something like `animals.name`.

To get the type I already find out that I could write: `const [animals, setAnimals] = useState<AnimalsListQueryResponse['animals']['edges']>()`
But because the that can be an array or null, I cannot go deeper. How could I solve it and get just the "right" Animal Type?

```
export type AnimalsListQueryResponse = {
readonly animals: {
    readonly edges: ReadonlyArray<{
        readonly node: {
            readonly id: string;
            readonly name: string;
            readonly age: number | null;
        };
    } | null> | null;
    readonly pageInfo: {
        readonly hasNextPage: boolean;
        readonly hasPreviousPage: boolean;
        readonly endCursor: string | null;
        readonly startCursor: string | null;
    };
    readonly totalCount: number;
};
```

};

Comment: And what should happen if it _is_ null?

Comment: Don't you use the GraphQL Code Generator to generate your types? https://www.the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen

Comment: Check out this npm package: [click me!](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@graphql-codegen/cli)

Comment: I am using relay. So basically I have the types, but they are inside the Response Types and quite deep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract the inner type of a single node, you can do something like `NonNullable<AnimalsListQueryResponse['animals']['edges']>[0]`

Note that your state indicates an array, not a single element.

And as mentioned in prev comments, use [GraphQL Code Generator](https://www.the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen). You will be amazed what this tool can do for you.